# Teamcity %build.vcs.number% not showing correctly

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity

I am using **TeamCity Enterprise 10.0.4 (build 42538)**

I am trying to use `%build.vcs.number%` to make the version appear.

What i did, is going to the specific build and filled `Build number format:` 
with `%build.vcs.number%`
[image]

When i am running the build, the version showing `???`

[image]

What is wrong? how can i make it show the `%build.vcs.number%`?

In build configuration parameters section, i see this parameter also:[image]

After deleting this parameter from "configuration parameters" section, it look like that:

[image]

Comment: Can you check parameters for specific build run/execution? Do you see this variable in that tab and what is the value?

Comment: Well, I was asking about actual parameters of executed build -- there should be a tab for finished build.
Anyway, this parameter is system one and you should not redefine it. Could you try remove it from configuration parameters and run again?

Comment: I removed it from configuration parameters and hit "run" again, now the version is appearing like this: `459ff60…59b6a38bb5d9` - also i updated the port and added an image showing that

Comment: also maybe it will help to figure, the issue with the version didn't exist before.
it started to exist when i moved the code from SVN to Github, when it was using SVN, the version was showing as expected.

Comment: So I assume it works now? 
There is a git sha1 hash displayed as vcs number.

Comment: maybe it is working but i dont know where this `git sha1` hash is coming from, the other builds are showing something like `#6.0.4.36` - i need it to show like that..

Comment: Check other build's configuration option `Build number format`. I believe it configured to something like `#6.0.4.%build.counter%`

Comment: nope, it's exactly the same `rev. %build.vcs.number%`

Comment: Have it been run recently or after setting this property? Maybe you see some outdated builds?

Comment: i ran them recently..

Comment: That's weird... Try to change it to some static value and after execution put back original value.