# What should be the value of build.vcs.number?

Tags: teamcity

I'm trying to figure out how to make the build work in TeamCity. One of the problems is that I cannot get the correct version. In *General settings* tab, I have a build counter which works well (it increments every time I run a build). However:

- If I don't define `build.vcs.number` in *Parameters*, TeamCity shows it anyway, marking that the value is required, and the parameter is undeletable.
- If I define `build.vcs.number` and set the value to an empty string, I end up with the version `1.0.0.`. If I set it to any value, such as 123, the version would be `1.0.0.123`.
- If I define `build.vcs.number` to be `%build.vcs.number%`, like in the third screenshot [in a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44130209/240613), it seems that the parameter just references itself, and TeamCity doesn't know what to do in this case, and I get `1.0.0.???`.

So how do I point `build.vcs.number` to the counter I see in *General settings*?

Comment: `build.vcs.number` is specific to your VCS. The build counter is `build.counter`. You shouldn't have to define them as build parameters. What are you trying to use the value for?

Comment: @DanielScott: can you please promote your comment to an answer? I'll accept it then (and remove my own, since it's redundant).

Comment: You must have edited the configuration to utilize the 'build.vcs.number' somewhere. When you force the usage of a parameter, and that parameter is not necessarily defined, that's when TeamCity will begin to show the yellow icon and warn that there is a parameter in use that is not defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`build.vcs.number` is specific to your VCS. The build counter is `build.counter`. You shouldn't have to define them as build parameters. What are you trying to use the value for?